# Rounding Off function to given decimal without using round function

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal, rounding

I am trying to write a function to round a floating point number up to n decimal places. The function can take one or two arguments. If there is only one argument the number should be rounded to two decimal places.

This is where I have gotten so far:

```
def roundno(num,point=2):
    import math
    x=1*(math.pow(10,-point))
    round=0
    while (num>x):
            while(num>0):
                    round+=num/10
                    num=num/10
                    round*=10
            round+=num/10
            num=num/10
            round*=0.1
    return round
```

I am getting infinity as the output, every time... Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how your algorithm is supposed to round numbers. I guess a similar strategy could work, but you'd need a subtraction in there somewhere...

One way to do this would be to convert the argument to a string, adjust the number of digits after the decimal point, and then convert the string back to a float, but I suspect that your teacher would not like that solution. :)

Here's a simple way to do rounding arithmetically:

```
def roundno(num, point=2):
    scale = 10.0 ** point
    return int(num * scale) / scale


data = [123, 12.34, 1.234, 9.8765, 98.76543]

for n in data:
    print n, roundno(n), roundno(n, 3)
```

**output**

```
123 123.0 123.0
12.34 12.34 12.34
1.234 1.23 1.234
9.8765 9.87 9.876
98.76543 98.76 98.765
```

This simply drops unwanted digits, but it's not hard to modify it to round up or off (your question isn't clear on exactly what type of rounding you want).

Note that this function doesn't check the `point` argument. It really should check that it's a non-negative integer and raise `ValueError` with an appropriate error message otherwise.